# HowTo create a Setup Project for AppFabric / workflow based applications

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, workflow-foundation-4, appfabric

i am interested in creating a setup tool for our business application which is based on a Windows Service and some WF4 workflows, currently hosted in IIS/AppFabric.

As long as i want to provide the best possible installing experience to our customers, I want to include IIS and Appfabric Setup Prerequirements as well as a WindowsService application into one Application-Setup Project.

Is there a proper way of doing this? Can someone give me some Links and/or Tips?

best regards,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard approach is to build a Deployment Package and import that into IIS. Is uses Web Deploy, see http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9278654 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

For client deployment using a setup project, I've been a fan of using WIX and an automated build script (MSBuild or Nant) in the past. It allows me the flexibility to script the build of the setup.exe, allowing me to make the changes I need (connection strings) in advance of deploying; leaving the entire process (regardless of environment [dev, prod, QC]) scriptable and automated.

For deploying the workflow components, its as simple as xcopy deployment which, like the above, is easily scriptable and automatable.